# String.Format with curly braces

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting, curly-braces

Our low level logging library has to cope with all sorts of log messages sent to it.

Some of these messages include curly braces (as part of the text), and some contain parameters to be formatted as part of the string using String.Format

For example, this string could be an input to the Logger class:

"Parameter: {Hostname} Value: {0}" 
With the correct variable sent to use for the formatter.

In order to properly do it, i must escape the curly braces that are not part of the formatting (by doubling them up).

I thought of doing it using Regex, however this is not as simple as it may seem, since i have no idea how to match these strings inside a curly braces (ones that are NOT used by String.Format for formatting purposes).

Another issue is that the Logger class should be as performance efficient as possible, starting to handle regular expressions as part of its operation may hinder performance.

Is there any proper and known best practice for this?

Comment: You are already saying you aer doubling them up (like this: `{{Hostname}}`. Why is that not working?

Comment: I didn't say i am doubling up. I said i must escape (double) the ones that are not related to formatting, or do something else to prevent this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing it in just one regex:

```
string input = "Parameter: {Hostname} Value: {0}";
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"{([^[0-9]+)}", @"{{$1}}");
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Outputs:

> Parameter: {{Hostname}} Value: {0}

This of course only works as long as there aren't any parameters that contain numbers but should still be escaped with `{{ }}`

Comment: Works great, i will profile to see how much we're actually hurting performance, but looks good.

Comment: Tried it on a 100 kB file containing "P: {Host} Val: {4}" repeated, took about 12 millisec. YMMV of course, but I can't see a concise way to do it any quicker.

Comment: This will hold until a redesign of the current logger. Many thanks, i wasn't too sure about all the matching details of the regex, need to strengthen that area anyways. Again, thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work if braces opened on one line, then close on a separate line, such as a function that spans many lines.

Answer (score 2):

I would double all the curly braces and then I would look for those to be replaced with a regex like `{{\d+}}` so that they came back to their original format -- {{0}} => {0} -- in your string.
So for each line I would do sth like this

```
string s = input.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}");
return Regex.Replace(s, @"{{(?<val>\d+)}}", 
                     m => { return "{" + m.Groups["val"] + "}"; }));
```

So that's a technical answer to the original question but @Anders Abel is perfectly right. It would be worth considering the design again...

Comment: This also fails to spot format placeholders that contain formating info e.g. "FourDigitHexValue={0:x4} Date={0:dd/MM/yyyy}".  See http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/ for more examples.

Comment: @Grmh for sure. This answer is just a quick workaround as it will depend on the inputs sent to the loggers. But as Anders Abel was saying, instead of going further with more complex regular expressions, another design review may be needed

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should look into your loggers interface. Compare with how `Console.WriteLine` works:

- `Console.WriteLine(String)` outputs exactly the string given, no formatting, nothing special with { and }.
- `Console.WriteLine(String, Object[])` outputs using formatting. { and } are special characters that the caller must escape to {{ and }}

I think it's flawed design having to differentiate between different curly brace occurences in the code to find out what as meant. Lay the burden of escaping { that should occur in the output into {{.

Comment: This is perfectly reasonable. We have a separation between the two, however i don't believe putting the responsibility on the caller on this case is possible since i cannot enforce this policy (i can't force the user of the logger to escape the string himself).

Comment: If the user is assumed to be competent enough to understand that {0} is a formatting option I think it can be safely assumed that the user can also escape { into {{. I think it is better to follow the principles used by other formatting aware APIs instead of inventing something special.

Comment: I agree with Anders.  You should ask the caller to do the escaping if they want to have formatting.

As a halfway, house you could implement a Log(string), Log(string, params object[]) as suggested by Anders and also provide a Log(bool, string, object[]) that will do the regex parsing - but mark it with the [Obsolete] attribute to discourage its use.

Answer (score 2):

To allow the caller to have formatted strings and cope with formitting specifiers e.g.

Logger.Log("{0:dd/mm/yyy} {0:hh:mm:ss} {hostname} Some error {1:x4} happened on {123Component}!", DateTime.UtcNow, 257)

You'd need a regex like:

```
string input = "{0:dd/mm/yyy} {0:hh:mm:ss} {hostname} Some error {1:x4} happened on {123Component}!";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\{[^[0-9}]+?[^}]*\}|\{(?![0-9]+:)[^}]+?\})");
string output = reg.Replace(input, "{$1}");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This outputs:

```
"{0:dd/mm/yyy} {0:hh:mm:ss} {{hostname}} Some error {1:x4} happened on {{123Component}}!"
```

But to reiterate, I'd agree with Anders Abel that you ought to redesign to avoid the need for the log library to do this.